# Methods of using filters in Laravel - what is the difference

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I try to learn Laravel, and I'd like to verify the user is logged in before calling a controller to do stuff.
There seems to be at least 3 different ways to accomplish this, and I'd like to know what is the difference between these.

```
Route::get('/main', 'StuffController@doStuff')->before('auth');

Route::get('/main', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'StuffController@doStuff'));
```

Or in the controllers constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no differences. Laravel is the Framework that allow you to accomplish many tasks in many ways.

I prefer to add filters in routes grouping them, for example:

```
// logged users paths
Route::group(
    ['before' => 'auth'],
    function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', [
                'as'   => 'dashboard',
                'uses' => 'DashboardController@mainPage'
            ]);
    }
);

// paths only for admin
Route::group(
    ['before' => 'admin'],
    function () {
        Route::get('/admin',
            ['as'   => 'admin_dashboard',
             'uses' => 'AdminDashBoardController@mainPage'
            ]);
        Route::get('/categories/{page?}',
            ['as'   => 'categories',
             'uses' => 'CategoryController@displayList'
            ])->where('page', '[1-9]+[0-9]*');
    }
);
```

There is one benefit of such use - its' much easier to look if all routes have correct filters.

Assume you want to display some content only for logged users and you need to use auth filter. You have many controllers to display content for logged users.

If you use `beforeFilter` directly in those controllers or in parent controllers constructor the following things can happen:

- you may forget to put beforeFilter in all your controller constructors
- you may forget in your controller constructor to run parent constructor (where you have beforeFilter)
- you may extend not the class you wanted (for example you extend BaseController and you have beforeFilter defined in AuthController and in one or some classes you extend BaseController)

Those situations can cause that you display content for unlogged users because you need to remember about auth filter it in each controller and if you want to make sure you did everything right, you need to look at code of all your controllers.

Using route grouping (as I showed above) you can easily look at one file (of course assuming you use one file for routing) and you will see which routes use `auth` filter and which don't.

Of course I assume many people will have their own opinion on that thing but that's me personal preference to use filters in routes.

Answer (score 1):

Your two ways have no difference, just different syntax style.

I prefer to put the auth filter in a `BaseController`, then extends all controllers I want to be authed from `BaseController`. Just write once, used everywhere. Btw, you can also put your `csrf` filter here.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
  }
}
```